# How to get write permissions on Linux host from Windows 10 guest, using virtiofs shared folders

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, libvirt, shared-folders, virtio

I am trying to share a folder from an Ubuntu 20.04.3 host with a Windows 10 build 19042 (20H2) guest, using QEMU 5.2 / libvirt 7.0.0 on the host and virtio-win 0.1.208 (driver 100.85.104.20800 and associated virtiofs service) on the guest.

So far I am able to read files in this host folder without problems from the guest. However I can only create/write/delete files if

1. I use a shell (Windows CMD or Cygwin bash) with *Administrator* rights on the guest
   OR
2. I change the folder permissions on the host, giving write permissions to "other".
   Neither of these options is acceptable as a permanent solution.

I already toyed with various settings for "user" in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf, including root and the user owning the shared folder (myself), without success. I do struggle to understand what ultimately determines the write permissions on the host folder. I had assumed this to be related to the UID of one of the hypervisor processes, so I do not see why running as Administrator or not on the guest should make a difference.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Has anyone been more succesful?

For info: The relevant section of the QEMU domain configuration looks like this:

```
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <driver type='virtiofs'/>
      <source dir='/home/micha'/>
      <target dir='hostfs'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
    </filesystem>
```

virtiofs requires `accessmode='passthrough'`.